# how can I loop this menu in a method?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I posted this question earlier on unrelated tag, sorry about that

```
package javaapplication50;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication50 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" > Enter students Grades: ");

        System.out.print(" >    Enter the grade of Aptitude Test :  ");
        double message = in.nextDouble();
        readStudentGrade(message);

        System.out.print(" >    Enter the grade of Introductory Year :  ");
        message = in.nextDouble();
        readStudentGrade(message);

        System.out.print(" >    Enter the grade of School :  ");
        message = in.nextDouble();
        readStudentGrade(message);


   public static double readStudentGrade(double message) {

        while (true) {
            if (message >= 0 && message <= 100) {
                return message;

            } else {

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(" >    Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)\n"
                        + " >    Please try again.");
                System.out.println("");
            }

            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the method `readStudentGrade()` with return type `double` and parameters `message` as a `String` (represent the name of Aptitude test or school grade). To allow the user to enter the one mark and returns it if the entered value between 0 and 100 inclusively. Otherwise, the method print the message and enforces the user to enter the correct mark. I couldn't figure out how to do it without causing infinite loop.

This this how output should be.

> Enter the grade of Aptitude Test :  120
>
> Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)
>      Please try again.
>
> Enter the grade of Aptitude Test :  90
>      Enter the grade of Introductory Year :  105
>
> Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)
>      Please try again.
>
> Enter the grade of Introductory Year :  92
>      Enter the grade of School :  150
>
> Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)
>      Please try again.
>
> Enter the grade of School :  95

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well it got down voted to hell. I deleted it .I'm kinda new to this site . May someone please answer my question

Comment: Surprisingly, one downvote is nowhere close  downvoted to hell.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a few issues:

1. You prompt the user for input before you enter the loop. They will never be re-prompted for input in this way. The prompt for input needs to go inside your while loop.
2. Your scan for the next input also takes place outside the while loop. This needs to occur within the loop.
3. You have a second `return message;` statement in your loop, that occurs outside the scope of the if/else statement. Thus, this return will execute at the end of the first iteration of the loop, regardless of whether or not the data entered by the user is valid. You need to remove this line.
4. More of a nitpicky thing, but the name `message` for the input to your `readStudentGrade` function is not appropriate. You are passing the grade you would like to check, a double. Perhaps a better name would be `grade`.

Here is one possible solution:

```
    public class JavaApplication50 {

        double getInput(double min, double max, String message, Scanner in) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(message);
                double input = in.nextDouble();
                if (input <= max && input >= min) {
                    return input;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input! (must be between " + min + " and " + max + ") Please try again.");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            JavaApplication50 app = new JavaApplication50();

            System.out.println("Enter student's Grades...");

            double aptTestGrade = app.getInput(0, 100, " > Enter the grade of Aptitude Test: ", in);
            double introYearGrade = app.getInput(0, 100, " > Enter the grade of Introductory Year: ", in);
            double schoolGrade = app.getInput(0, 100, " > Enter the grade of School: ", in);

            System.out.print("Grades summary: \nAptitude Test: " + aptTestGrade + "\nIntroductory year: " + introYearGrade
                    + "\nSchool: " + schoolGrade);
        }
    }
```

Notice how the method `getInput` accepts a minimum, maximum, and message as parameters. It could additionally accept an error message for even more flexibility.

Comment: A good answer but no thanks for it. It is not my question but I want to say thanks for a great solution.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh - thanks! Feel free to suggest improvements - they're always welcome

Answer (score 0):

you may also try this if it is suitable .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Demo{
     public static void main(String arg[])
     {
        int no=0;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter students Grades:");
        double message;
        outer:while(true)
        {
            switch(no)
            {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Enter the grade of Aptitude Test :");
                    message = in.nextDouble();
                    if(message<0 | message>100)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)\n >    Please try again.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        no++;break;
                    }

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter the grade of Introductory Year :");
                    message = in.nextDouble();
                    if(message<0 | message>100)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)\n >    Please try again.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        no++;
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter the grade of School :");
                    message = in.nextDouble();
                    if(message<0 | message>100)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)\n >    Please try again.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        no++;
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    break outer;
            }
         }
    }
```

}
this mat help you to figure out the solution.

Comment: and you can replace the if condition that check the value of message like

if(!checkValue(message))
{
 break;
}
else
{
 no++; break;
}


//checkValue Message
public boolean checkValue(double msg)
{
 if(message<0 | message>100)
        {
         System.out.println("Invalid input! (must be between 0 and 100)\n >    Please try again.");
         return false;        
         }
         else
          return true;
}